# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in header.php

Tags: wordpress

This error keeps looping and my error_log keeps increasing.

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in header.php on line 491

```html
<?php 
// (get_option_tree('theme_skin', '', false)!=""&&get_option_tree('theme_skin', '', false)!="Default") || 
if(true){

 $theme_background_color="#3f92a8"; 

// if(get_option_tree('theme_background_color', '', false)!="")

//    $theme_background_color=get_option_tree('theme_background_color', '', false); 

if(!isset($_GET['presets'])){

if($_GET['presets']=='preset1')

    $theme_background_color='#3f92a8';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset2')

    $theme_background_color='#b71010';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset3')

    $theme_background_color='#E16204';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset4')

    $theme_background_color='#1b5e88';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset5')

    $theme_background_color='#13D7FD';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset6')

    $theme_background_color='#685518';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset7')

    $theme_background_color='#5B2F2A';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset8')

    $theme_background_color='#6A6664';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset9')

    $theme_background_color='#C53D96';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset10')

    $theme_background_color='#62CDDF';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset11')

    $theme_background_color='#AD00B4';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset12')

    $theme_background_color='#6000A0';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset13')

    $theme_background_color='#990';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset14')

    $theme_background_color='#353535';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset15')

    $theme_background_color='#706852';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset16')

    $theme_background_color='#BCDD39';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset17')

    $theme_background_color='#FC0';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset18')

    $theme_background_color='#600';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset19')

    $theme_background_color='#FF7400';

if($_GET['presets']=='preset20')

    $theme_background_color='#b0c288';

}



?>

<div class="grid_10 abr-omega" id="slogan">
  <div class="socialMedia">
    <div class="socialIco"><span></span></div>
    <div style="text-align: right;" class="smile">
    <?php
    $slides = get_option_tree('sm_icons', $option_tree, false, true, -1);
    
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
    
      echo '<a href="' . $slide['link'] . '"><img src="' . $slide['image'] . '" alt="' . $slide['title'] . '" /></a>
      ';
    }
    ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how to fix this? This is from a WordPress theme.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. `$slides` should be an array not empty or string.

```
$slides = get_option_tree('sm_icons', $option_tree, false, true, -1);

if(count($slides)>0){
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {

      echo '<a href="' . $slide['link'] . '"><img src="' . $slide['image'] . '" alt="' . $slide['title'] . '" /></a>
      ';
    }
}
```